# Getting a invalid bug ID error when tried to link a defect to a test case using and external bug tracking tool “Instabug”

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I was integrating an external bug tracker tool “Instabug” to Kiwi but when i tried to link a bug to the test case it shows invalid bug ID error.

1. For setting up the external bug tracking tool i performed the following steps: 
   ADMIN -> Everything Else -> TEST Cases -> Bug Trackers -> Add Bug Tracker -> Filled all the Details -> Save.
2. The fields which i am not sure about whether i filled them correct or not are :
   (a) URL format string : https%3A%2F%2Fdashboard.instabug.com%2Fapplications%2FProjectname%2Fbeta%2Fbugs
   (b) RegExp for ID validation : ^\d$
3. I am not sure whether the connection is established between Kiwi and Instabug.

I expect to know what are the correct values of 
(a) URL format string 
(b) RegExp for ID validation

and if i entered the wrong or right value in the bug tracker detail then it should show the connection with the bug tracker is established or not.

Also i am not sure if i have to make any changes in the “Instabug" site?

Kindly help me with the setup of “Instabug” with Kiwi.

Answer (score 0):

a) Did you set **Type** to **LinkOnly**?

b) Connection status with tracker is not yet present - see https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/97

c) Post relevant docker container logs.

Comment: [Kiwi-tcms] @prome

(a). Yes i’ve set type to LinkOnly.

(b). What values should i entered for 
(1) URL format string
(2) RegExp for ID validation

Still it’s not working i am not able to link defects to Kiwi.